# Beldum Farming/Reset ORAS

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can I download Beldum (Ger:Tanhiel) once per savegame or once per cartridge.
because I'm going to buy OR and want to farm Tanhiel.
so if I reset the game(after I transferred the Tanhiel to pokebank) do they reset the wondercard so I can download it again.

Comment: For reference, Tanhiel is (I believe) the German name for Beldum

Comment: Yeah you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/792673-pokemon-omega-ruby/70582971):

> Once per save file. To get another one, you need to restart your game.

Comment: So this will work without any tools just start a new game,right?

Comment: You only have to reset your savefile pressing Up + B + X simultaneously from the title screen.